# Vite hot update only works for App.vue but not for components

Tags: visual-studio-code, vuejs3, vite

I have created a fresh vue3/vite stack and noticed that the hot reload only works for the App.vue file but not for components in the components folder.
If I stop and restart "npm run dev" the updates on the component file takes effect.

I have vite 4.0.0, vue 3.2.45 and vscode 1.74.1

Comment: can you share an code example? and your project structure.